# 'Message' object has no attribute msg

Tags: python, discord.py

so i was trying to find a way to have a message deleted if it contained bad words ***(i mean by finding i just copied some code)***

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.id == client.user.id:
        return
    msg_content = message.content.lower()

    curseWord = ["cursewords i put"]




    if any(word in msg_content for word in curseWord):
        await message.delete()
        msg = "**`Watch your mouth boiii`**"
        await message.channel.send(msg)
        await message.msg.add_reaction("⚠")
```

i was trying to add a reaction to the message but i said

```
'Message' object has no attribute msg
```

Comment: Looks like you just need `await message.add_reaction("⚠")`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error probably also points you to the line

```
await message.msg.add_reaction("⚠")
```

As the message says `message` doesn't have an attribute called `msg`. You can use [`add_reaction`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message.add_reaction) directly on your message object.

```
await message.add_reaction("⚠")
```

But `message` is referring to the message that you deleted, so you don't want to add a reaction to that message. Instead, to add the reaction to the message you just sent you need to get that message object and use it. To get it, when you did `message.channel.send` the message object was [sent back](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.TextChannel.send), we just need to save it.

```
sent_msg = await message.channel.send(msg)
```

And now we can use it to add a reaction. Altogether that looks like

```
if any(word in msg_content for word in curseWord):
    await message.delete()
    msg = "**`Watch your mouth boiii`**"
    sent_msg = await message.channel.send(msg)
    await sent_msg.add_reaction("⚠")
```

Comment: no it errors even more because its trying to add a reaction to a deleted message

Comment: Does my answer fix your problem now?

Comment: nope and i am using @client.command so it broke my bot

Comment: What error are you getting now?

Comment: it works thanks!